# SQL calculate row number

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I doing league table football and There is a profile of Team (Like : Team.php?team=XXX) 
In this page I want to show, What position of TeamXXX in League Table

Page League Table

```
    <?php 
    $number = 0;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `leaguetable` WHERE `league` = 'leaguename' ORDER BY pts DESC";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    while($rs=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $number++;
    ?>
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Position</th>
<th>Team</th>
<th>Points</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<td><?php echo $number; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $rs['team']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $rs['pts']; ?></td>
</tbody>
</table>
<?php } ?>
```

Data in Table `leaguetable`

```
id        team           pts
```

In team.php I want to show position of TeamXXX

```
<?php
    $getTeam = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `leaguetable` WHERE `team`='"$_GET['team']"'");
?>
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Position</th>
<th>Team</th>
<th>Points</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<td>#########</td>
<td><? echo $getTeam['team']; ?></td>
<td><? echo $getTeam['pts']; ?></td>
</tbody>
</table>
```

How can I know what position of teamXXX in leaguetable?
Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much

Comment: can do this in mysql with variables

Comment: Since the teams are ORDERed by score (`pts DESC`), doesn't `$number` give you the position?

Comment: depends how you define position ( what about when two teams are tied )

Comment: I mean in Team.php Page. There is <th>Position</th> And How to show position of team[GET VALUE]?

Comment: Team.php?team=xxxx , I want to know position of xxxx. Only xxxx team

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**query**

```
select id, team, pts, rnk
from
(
select leag.id, leag.team, leag.pts,
@rnk := if(leag.pts = @lag, @rnk,
           if(@lag := leag.pts, @rnk + 1, @rnk + 1)) as rnk
from leaguetable leag
cross join ( select @rnk := 0, @lag := null ) params
where league = 'FA Cup'
order by leag.pts desc
) rankings
where team = 'Chelsea'
;
```

**example.php**

```
<?php

/**
 * Mysqli initial code
 * 
 * User permissions of database
 * Create, Alter and Index table, Create view, and Select, Insert, Update, Delete table data
 * 
 * @package         PhpFiddle
 * @link            http://phpfiddle.org
 * @since           2012
*/

require_once "dBug!.php";

require "util/public_db_info.php";

$short_connect = new mysqli($host_name, $user_name, $pass_word, $database_name, $port);

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

/*
$sql = "create table leaguetable"
     . "("
     . "  id integer primary key not null,"
     . "  team varchar(33) not null,"
     . "  pts integer not null default 0"
     . ");";

$result = $short_connect->query($sql);

if(!$result)
{
    die("Create table failed : " . mysqli_error($short_connect));
}

$sql = "insert into leaguetable"
     . "( id, team, pts )"
     . "values"
     . "( 1, 'Liverpool', 22 ),"
     . "( 2, 'Arsenal', 29 ),"
     . "( 3, 'Chelsea', 23 ),"
     . "( 4, 'Tottenham', 23)";

$result = $short_connect->query($sql);

if(!$result)
{
    die("insert failed : " . mysqli_error($short_connect));
}
*/

//get all tables in the database
//$sql = "SHOW TABLES";

//get column information from a table in the database
//$sql="SELECT COLUMN_KEY, COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_TYPE FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'books'";

//SQL statement for a table in the database
$sql = "select id, team, pts, rnk "
     . "from"
     . "("
     . "select leag.id, leag.team, leag.pts,"
     . "@rnk := if(leag.pts = @lag, @rnk,"
     . "           if(@lag := leag.pts, @rnk + 1, @rnk + 1)) as rnk "
     . "from leaguetable leag "
     . "cross join ( select @rnk := 0, @lag := null ) params "
     . "    where league = 'FA Cup' "
     . "order by leag.pts desc;"
     . ") rankings "
     . where team = 'Chelsea';";

//result is boolean for query other than SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE and EXPLAIN
$result = $short_connect->query($sql);

if (($result) && ($result->num_rows > 0))
{
    echo "<table>" . "<thead>" . "<tr>" . "<th>Position</th>" . "<th>Team</th>" . "<th>Points</th>" . "</tr>" . "</thead>" . "<tbody>";
    //convert query result into an associative array
        echo "<tr><td>" . $row['rnk'] . "</td><td>" . $row['team'] . "</td><td>" . $row['pts'] . "</td></tr>";
   echo "</tbody></table>";
}
else
{
    die("select failed : " . mysqli_error($short_connect));
}

$short_connect->close();


?>
```

**output**

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Team</th>
      <th>Points</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Chelsea</td>
      <td>23</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b109e/2)

Comment: I got it, Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using two queries (I wouldn't mind it), it's pretty easy: Just count how many teams have more points, and add one (so that if three teams are tied in second position, they all get position 2).

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT count(*)+1 AS POSTN FROM leaguetable WHERE 
                                league = 'leaguename' AND pts > $points");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$position = $row["POSTN"];
```

Doing it in one query is a bit messier, since you need to embed this query in your original one:

```
"SELECT *, (SELECT count(*)+1 FROM leaguetable table2 
                WHERE league = 'leaguename' AND table2.pts > leaguetable.pts) AS POSTN 
     FROM leaguetable WHERE team = '$currentteam'"
```

But why are you using the `mysql_*` API for new code? Haven't you noticed all the [dire warnings in pink boxes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) in the documentation? Do yourself a favor and switch to `mysqli` today, starting with this program.

Also: **Never** just inject `$_GET[param]` into your query string! You're giving yourself an SQL injection attack waiting to happen... and brittle, error-prone code until then.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help

```
$number = 0;
    $points=0;
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `leaguetable` WHERE `league` = 'leaguename' ORDER BY pts DESC";
        $query = mysql_query($sql);
        while($rs=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
        if($points!=$rs['pts'])
            $number++;

    if($rs['team']==$_GET['team']){
        if($points==$rs['pts'])
            $position=$number-1;
        else
            $position=$number;
    }
    $poins=$rs['pts'];
    }
```